# Stop wrapping text around font awesome icons

Tags: html, css

Hi actually i tried to prevent the text that wrapping around the font awesome icons. I tried so many methods. but those didn't work in this case. Please help me to fix this.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.fa {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="dashboard-profile-wrp dashboard-todo">
  <p><i class="fa fa-rocket mob-mnu-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="" title=""></i><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b>    and grow your sales beyond your local and national boundaries.and grow your sales beyond your local and national</p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b> and grow your sales beyond your
    local and national boundaries.and grow your salesgrow your sales </p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b> and grow your sales beyond your local
    and national boundaries.and grow your sales beyond your local and national boundaries.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: `.fa {display:block !important}` should be all you need here.

Comment: Actually i want the icons to be left and the text to be right. i want the text which is around the icons appear on right side.

Comment: `.dashboard-profile-wrp {
 position: relative;
}   
.dashboard-profile-wrp p {
 margin-left: 35px;
}   
.fa {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 margin-right: 10px;
 font-size: 20px !important;
}`

Comment: with negative text-indent and positive margin-left you can get the effect you want, but i think put icon and text in separate divs would be better

Comment: "Actually i want"  When you want something specific, it's usually a good idea to say that in the question, so we don't have to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.fa {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="dashboard-profile-wrp dashboard-todo">
  <p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-rocket mob-mnu-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="" title=""></i></p>
  <a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b>    and grow your sales beyond your local and national boundaries.and grow your sales beyond your local and national</p>
  <p><p><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></p><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b> and grow your sales beyond your
    local and national boundaries.and grow your salesgrow your sales </p>
  <p><p><i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title=""></p>Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b> and grow your sales beyond your local
    and national boundaries.and grow your sales beyond your local and national boundaries.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: first your code is invalid, second this is not what the OP want and third you added 0 explanation on what you did .. and you got upvoted

Comment: I want to show both icons and text in the same row.  Only the text which is around the icon needs to be right aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Give the paragraphs a left padding, and move the icon left using `text-indent`:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

p {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.fa {
  text-indent: -1.3em;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="dashboard-profile-wrp dashboard-todo">
  <p><i class="fa fa-rocket mob-mnu-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-original-title="" title=""></i><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b>    and grow your sales beyond your local and national boundaries.and grow your sales beyond your local and national</p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b> and grow your sales beyond your
    local and national boundaries.and grow your salesgrow your sales </p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="/dashboard/boost-your-sales.html" class="link" data-original-title="" title="">Upgrade Membership</a> to <b>connect with buyers like never before</b> and grow your sales beyond your local
    and national boundaries.and grow your sales beyond your local and national boundaries.</p>

</div>
```